# Are there any PHP IDEs that handle entry points?

Tags: linux, php

I'm trying to work with (read: fork) phpBB 2, but one of the problems I'm running into is that the PHP IDEs I've tried (so far, eclipse, because I already had that installed) have met me with a long list of warnings about undefined variables which, in practice, aren't actually undefined.

This means they're effectively unusable for anything but single-file php apps.

Are there any PHP IDEs that can take into account the execution context of the php files (read: where they're included/required)?

Comment: I have developed multi-page PHP apps with Eclipse for 15 years or more, and never had a problem.

Comment: you should give phpBB 2.0.x a try. it's very obvious what I'm talking about once you try it.

Comment: Could it be that you copied all the code, but not the actual Eclipse project, then made your own new Eclipse project from the code? For an established project such as this, I would expect a project to be available for at least one IDE - without any errors or warnings.

Comment: @Mawg https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/tree/2.0.x good luck

Comment: I would highly recommend PHPStorm by JetBrains: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm. It certainly does look at included files, and does much more besides. It has a free trial, and heavy discounts for open source projects, education ,etc.